# Running a Laravel Application alongside another app

Tags: php, laravel, routes

So I have a question relating running a Laravel application alongside another application and how I can achieve getting past (or utilising) Laravel's routing to run them in harmony.

So assume we have the following file structure

```
Public_html
  /public - holding Laravel files
  /billing - holding WHMCS
```

How can I get around Laravel not finding routes and throwing an exception? Could I deploy the Laravel app to find the index of public in the root folder instead?

Comment: Both these application same name?

Comment: Nope, different names

Comment: Did you find any confliction between the two apps.

Comment: In the past i have had allot of trouble doing this under any configuration, its not that i have found any particular issues with this setup (i.e yet to test with WHMCS specifically).This question is more of a general question about running another application that might have things like SEO friendly URLs alongside a Laravel application.